# Coldfusion: How to loop over query from function

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a query that gets called multiple times depending on the the variable vchrStatus

```
<cffunction name="getGalleriesByStatus" output="no" returntype="query">
    <cfargument name="vchrStatus" type="string" required="yes">
    <cfquery 
        name="getGalleries"
        datasource="#Application.dsn#">
        /// Long complicated query in here
    </cfquery>
    <cfset var result="#getGalleries#">
    <!--- Return it --->
    <cfreturn result>
</cffunction>
```

I tested the function with cfdump and it is outputing the desired results.

Now I want to loop over the results in a cfoutput

```
<cfoutput query="getGalleriesByStatus('Pending')">
```

But I'm getting the error: The value of the attribute query, which is currently getGalleriesByStatus('Pending'), is invalid.

Comment: What's the purpose of juggling the query object from one variable to another before returning it?  If this function is inside of a CFC, you already have a var-scoping issue because the initial query name getGalleries is going in the (shared) variables scope.  You need to call it local.getGalleries or add a <cfset var getGalleries = ""> to the top of the function.  Also, wrapping a variable in pound signs and then quotes is redundant as it just cancels itself out. <cfset var result = getGalleries> is sufficient.

Comment: I'm really at the point in my Coldfusion where I think using CFC's is necessary or even possible. Baby steps.

Comment: @JackPilowsky just use `<cfquery name="local.getGalleries">` and `<cfreturn local.getGalleries>` to make it thread-safe :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`<cfoutput>` takes the *name* of the query variable (ie: a string). It does not take an expression which evaluates to a query. So you need this:

```
<cfset someVar = getGalleriesByStatus('Pending')>
<cfoutput query="someVar">
```

This is counter-intuitive, but is the case. It's also not in the docs, which sux.